# add data to exist list in realtime database in firebase in android

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have a list in my firebase database contains download urls from firebase storage.

Now I want to append this list with some data, but I can't do that.

My data in firebase with this structure:

[image: this structure]

this is my code

```
private void uploadExtrasToStorage(String cert_num, List<Uri> list) {
    StorageReference sRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
            .getReference("Certificates").child(cert_num);
    dialog.startDialog();
    for (Uri uri : list) {
        StorageReference mRef = sRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis() +
                "." + Tools.getFileExtn(getApplicationContext(), uri));
        mRef.putFile(uri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d("Upload", "Uploading successfull");
                    mRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            urls.add(uri.toString());
                            DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase
                                    .getInstance().getReference("Database")
                                    .child("Certificates");
                            dbRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                                        for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                            Modal modal = ds.getValue(Modal.class);
                                            if (modal != null) {
                                                if (modal.getCert_num().equals(cert_num)) {
                                                    model = modal;
                                                    oldUrls = model.getList();
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                Log.e("Error", "Modal object is null");
                                            }
                                        }
                                        newUrls = Tools.mergeLists(oldUrls, urls);
                                        Log.d("myList (old)", oldUrls + "");
                                        Log.d("myListSize (old)", oldUrls.size() + "");
                                        Log.d("myList (urls)", urls + "");
                                        Log.d("myListSize (urls)", urls.size() + "");
                                        Log.d("myList", newUrls + "");
                                        Log.e("myList CURRENT", newUrls.size() + "");
                                    }
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

how can I achieve that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?